# Starting LEMP server at startup

Tags: 12.10, server, startup, webserver, nginx

Based on [this blog post](http://goo.gl/3VMpv) I've installed LEMP server. Is there any easy way to add this web server: PHP-FPM, Nginx, MySQL into startup applications list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install a service in ubuntu it is by default automatically started at every system start. So there is no need to add them to any list.